How would one change the settings of a shader based on the value of a slider?
I want to have a slider that the player uses to change how a shader affects the color of a sprite.
Here is the shader:
shader_type canvas_item;
uniform vec4 color : source_color;
void fragment(){
    vec4 pixelColor = texture(TEXTURE, UV);
    float brightness = (0.7 * pixelColor.r + 0.7 * pixelColor.g + 0.70 * pixelColor.b);
    vec4 greyScale = vec4(brightness, brightness, brightness, pixelColor.a);
    COLOR = greyScale * color;

I've been testing it with this button that randomizes the color and it's great:
func _on_button_pressed():
    material.set_shader_parameter("color", Color(randf(), randf(), randf(), 1.0))

Now I want to be able to control the hue of the color.
I have made a class script for the hues levels. I then imported it to the script that contains the sliders and sprite as a variable.
class HueClass:
    var red = Color(0.7607843137, 0.0823529412, 0.0823529412, 1.0); //it goes on throughout the rainbow

I'm kind of lost on what to do next though! I thought of doing something like this:
var ShaderParam = preload("res://...")

func _on_hue_value_changed(value):
    HueClass[value]
    if value == 0:
        ShaderParam.set_shader_parameter("color",HueClass.red)
    print(value)

but I got an error saying "Invalid get index '2' (on base:GDscript)". If anyone could point me into the right direction, let me know. Thank you.

what is the usage of HueClass[value] ?

I'm not entirely sure tbh. I was just trying to follow a tutorial for setting up slider values. In my head, I thought of  HueClass[value] as the slider getting the value from the keys in HueClass, but I guess that's not what it's doing.

Oh, wait, I see. I accidentally labled the class as HueCodes. I'll change that real quick.

I figured it out!
Instead of making the colors a class, I've made them into a dictionary and then made an array that sorts each dictionary key!
var Hues := {
    "red": Color(0.7607843137, 0.0823529412, 0.0823529412, 1.0), .....}
var HueArray = ["red", "orange", .....]

func _on_hue_value_changed(value):
    HueArray[value]
    if value == 0:
        material.set_shader_parameter("color",Hues.red)
    if value == 1:
        material.set_shader_parameter("color",Hues.redorange)
    print(HueArray[value])

Now the slider changes the color of the sprite and it also prints out the name of the color it's on! I'm so happy! This is my first time figuring out how to work a code without directly copying from someone else!!

Bonus tip: you can use enums to define your colors instead of strings array & dictionary and match instead of if else, Also Color has some already defined constants if you'd like to use them e.g. Color.RED

Also you might want to look into keys() method of a Dictionary, it automatically returns an Array if order isn't important in your case

Hey, thanks! Would you be able to do an example of a match statement? I'm trying to look into it and I can't seem to figure out how to make it apply to my code

I'm still not certain on what you're trying to do but you can use match like this
var Hues := {
    "red": Color(0.7607843137, 0.0823529412, 0.0823529412, 1.0), .....}
var HueArray = ["red", "orange", .....]

func _on_hue_value_changed(value):
    match(value):
        0:
            material.set_shader_parameter("color",Hues.red)
        1:
            material.set_shader_parameter("color",Hues.redorange)

    print(HueArray[value])

